# Explain what is Virtual LAN

Tags: vlan

Can someone simply explain what Virtual LAN is and how it works?
Or you can clarify the Wiki article:

> A virtual LAN (VLAN) is any broadcast domain that is partitioned and
>   isolated in a computer network at the data link layer (OSI layer
>   2). A LAN is an abbreviation for local area network and in this
>   context virtual refers to a physical object recreated and altered by
>   additional logic. VLANs work through tags within network packets and
>   tag handling in networking systems - recreating the appearance and
>   functionality of network traffic that is physically on a single
>   network but acts as if it is split between separate networks. In this
>   way, VLANs can keep networks separate despite being connected to the
>   same network, and without requiring multiple sets of cabling and
>   networking devices to be deployed.

Comment: The WP article is rather straightforward - do you have specific questions?

Comment: Just an explanation for "dummies" I guess.

Comment: Try these articles, start from the oldest:  [pracnet.net/vlans](http://pracnet.net/vlans).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A LAN is a group of devices connected to the **same** network that can commuicate among them.

A virtual LAN is a group of devices that using a predefined `tag` in the ethernet frames can communicate among them. They are isolated of other devices *in the same network* that don't use the same tag.

[image]

In the diagram all the devices are connected to the same switch (single network) but there are two VLANs (`Sales` and `Finance`) so all the `Sales` devices can communicate among them but **can't** communicate with the `Finance`devices.

The devices (PCs in this case) are unaware of the existence of a VLAN. The VLAN tag is configured in the switch port and the switch is the network equipment that is VLAN-aware.

Answer (score 1):

Before coming to the concept of virtual LANs, let me describe a few terminology:

1. Broadcast domain : Every network represents a broadcast domain. E.g 10.0.0.0/8 is one broadcast domain; 20.0.0.0/8 is another broadcast domain. In general, every interface of a router represents a broadcast domain. For devices in one broadcast domain, to talk to devices in another broadcast domain, we need a Layer3 device (called a Router).

So essentially, as we place a router in a network and assign ip addresses, we are creating new broadcast domains.

2. By default,all the devices connected to a switch  are part of *same* broadcast domain.They can talk to one another without the need of a layer 3 device.

So, what is a VLAN ?

A VLAN gives us the ability to create separate broadcast domains, even though the devices are connected to a layer 2 switch. To make devices in one vlan talk to devices in another vlan, we would need a Router or a Layer 3 device.

Comment: "_A switch is a layer 2 device and has all it's interfaces (in general) in the same collision domain._" No. That is true of a hub, but each interface on a switch represents a different collision domain.

Comment: @RonMaupin corrected, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The term VLAN is a bit confusing because it's used in two related but subtly different ways. Depending on context it can refer to.

1. The tag number used in VLAN tags to create virtual networks.
2. The virtual Ethernet network created through the use of VLAN tags.

VLANs let us split a single physical Ethernet network into multiple virtual Ethernet networks. This is done by tagging the packets as they pass over "trunk" links that carry multiple VLANs. The tags are normally removed before the packets are sent to end systems.

There are many reasons we may want to do this including but not limited to.

1. Forcing traffic between certain systems to go via an IP router/firewall and blocking any attempts at direct communication between them.
2. Preventing systems from communicating with each other at all.
3. Controlling where broadcast traffic goes and reducing the amount of it in any given part of the network.
4. Separating multiple systems with the same IP address.

Many network admins keep a 1:1 mapping between VLANs and IP subnets and that certainly makes life simpler but VLANs and subnets are different concepts at different layers and there certainly doesn't have to be a 1:1 mapping.

Similarly in many smaller networks there is likely to be a 1:1 mapping between VLAN tag numbers and virtual Ethernet networks, but as networks grow beyond a certain size that is no longer practical to maintain as there are only about 4000 usable VLAN tag numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual LAN can defined as logical segmentation of network.

Network traffic can be segregates or isolated as per business requirements . Due to this isolation most of the security threads can be limited within same VLANs.

VLANs can also used  to separate traffic to increase security of networks.